# Probability of non fair coin problem

Tags: probability

Imagine that I have a black bag containing two coins, a fair one (having **1 H** and **1 T** with 50% probability of landing on each side) and a non fair one (**2H**).

I draw a coin at random and it lands heads up *n* times out of *n* tosses.

The question is to find the probability that it is a fair coin.

I've been thinking about this for quite a while but couldn't come up with a solution and I don't even know if this question has a valid numeric answer!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: My Bayes sense is tingling ... Let $F=\text{coin is fair}$ and $X_n =n~ \text{heads in a row out of }~n$. Now Bayes tell us that
$$
P(F|X_n) = \frac{P(X_n|F)P(F)}{P(X_n|F)P(F)+P(X_n| \bar F)P(\bar F)}
$$

Comment: can't you use the binomial distribution to check if it deviates a lot from it?

Comment: Yes.  $X_n$ is conditionally binomial for a given fairness or bias.  $$X_n\mid F\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n,1/2)\\X_n\mid\overline F\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n,1)\quad$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using Baye's rule. Define:

$F$: Coin is fair

$H_n$: $n$ heads in $n$ tosses

We are interested in computing $P(F|H_n)$. This can be written using Baye's rule as:

$P(F|H_n) = \frac{P(F, H_n)}{P(H_n)}$ = $\frac{P(H_n|F)P(F)}{P(H_n|F)P(F) + P(H_n|\bar{F})P(\bar{F})}$

where $\bar{F}$ is the event that the coin is not fair. The denominator follows from the law of total probability.

Now let's evaluate each of the terms individually:

$P(F) = P(\bar{F}) = 1/2$, since there are two coins, and each one is equally likely to be picked.

$P(H_n|F) = \frac{1}{2^n}$, since each toss has a probability of $1/2$ of showing up heads

$P(H_n|\bar{F}) = 1$, since the biased coin will always show heads.

Putting it all together: $P(F|H_n) = \frac{1 / 2^{n+1}}{1 / 2^{n+1} + 1/2} = \frac{1}{1 + 2^n}$.

Note that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $P(F|H_n) \rightarrow 0$. Intuitively, if you continue to get heads, the probability that you picked the fair coin keeps decreasing.